# invalid: spec.containers[0].resources.requests: Invalid value: "N": must be less than or equal to cpu limit

Tags: kubernetes

Small question regarding Kubernetes for a SpringBoot app, and the CPU request vs limit please.

I have a question based on a talk made by VMWare team, found here:
Production Considerations for Spring on Kubernetes
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hAHXp_jQWVo

It says, the application should set the request CPU, but not set the limit.
Please see attached screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Therefore, I went and did the same for my app, which is running in AWS, question applies for a on prem Kubernetes setup.

```
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: myapp
          image: mydocker.com/myapp
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: "2000m"
```

However, my app does not start, and I can only see this error.

```
NAME                                       DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/myapp-846c4f4fdb          1         1         0       56s

  Warning  FailedCreate  114s                replicaset-controller  Error creating: Pod "myapp-846c4f4fdb-vq4cs" is invalid: spec.containers[0].resources.requests: Invalid value: "2": must be less than or equal to cpu limit
```

It is then working if I do set explicitly the limit (which is not what the talk is suggesting).

Did I miss something from the setup I made?
How do I avoid limiting the CPU please?

Thank you

Comment: What is the output if you `kubectl describe` your pods and replicaset? Also do you have any limits on your namespace?
By the way keep in mind that having no CPU limit means that your pods can request unreasonable amounts of resources. See [kuberbetes docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/assign-cpu-resource/#motivation-for-cpu-requests-and-limits)

Comment: The error seems pretty clear; you haven't declared limits, only requests.

Comment: I understand that, and I am doing it on purpose, if you look at the screenshots, it is what is suggested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe your cluster namespace has defined a `LimitRange` https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/limit-range/

Comment: This is correct @Ildefonso. If this is setup, my setup will not take effect. Thank you